# If $\cos x=\frac{12}{13}$ and $\sin y=\frac{7}{25}$ then what is $\cos y$ and $\sin x$?

Tags: trigonometry

Let $\cos x=\frac{12}{13}$ and $\sin y=\frac{7}{25}$.

Determine  $\cos y$ and $\sin x$.

I know that there are basic ways of solving this, such as considering a right triangle, or using the Pythagorean theroem writing $\sin x =\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}$, but I was wondering if we could use another basic identity to solve the problem such as the sum or difference identity?

Thanks.

Comment: Please correct the typo! $\sin y$ occurs twice, and it is not clear which one is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the correction

Comment: Note:  $5^2+12^2=13^2$ and $7^2+24^2=25^2$, so $\sin x=\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}$ and $\cos x=\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$ work well

Comment: Your question was more general or you want an answer for those values 12/13 and 7/25

Comment: Then I must say your Pythagorean identity looks like the simplest way to solve this type of problem. In what way do you consider it not to be basic? Having said that, you might recognise $(12,13)$ and $(7,25)$ as being elements of the Pythagorean triples $(5,12,13)$ and $(7,24,25)$, which gives you the answer immediately.

Comment: I never said it wasn't a basic solution, just that I wanted to see if it could be solved using a different method.

Comment: by the way, just to point out a small detail: so far you haven't (explicitly) placed any restrictions on what range of values $x$ or $y$ lie in, so it is possible that $\sin x$ is either positive or negative (similarly for $\cos y$). Hence, you should consider both signs of the square root.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. There are two moderately well known integer right triangles here,
$$
(? , 12, 13) \text{ and } (7, ? , 25) \ .
$$
You can find them with the Pythagorean theorem.

There is nothing "more basic" in trigonometry.

Comment: I wanted to use an identity that is commonly used such as sum identity, or product identity,....  if such a solution exists

Comment: Any other trigonometric identity you might use (and I don't know any that do the job) would in fact be proved by using the Pythagorean theorem in some form.